# Excel VBA: Skip an Entire Row from Processing If Condition Is Met

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hello everyone I am relatively new to VBA coding in Excel (current version 2010) and I am trying to improve upon a simple program that suppresses small values in the tables my organization releases. The format of my data is as follows.

In the leftmost column (usually C) I have the row labels (e.g., Hospital, Home, Other, Missing Data). In following column we have the number of records in that category. In the last column we have a percentage value for that row.

When reporting out results we always suppress cell sizes from 1-5. However, we do not suppress the number of records in the "Missing Data" row.

I have generated the following macro with the assistance of other users on this forum a program which replaces all n values in our tables with "<6". The reason for the format statement is I don't want to suppress percentages and they are always formatted as numeric with a single decimal point.

```
Sub SuppressN()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Selection
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each cell In rng.Cells
   If cell.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0" And cell.Value >= 1 And 
   cell.Value <= 5 Then cell.Value = "<6"
Next
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is tell Excel that if it finds the string "Missing Data" to not run the code for **all values in that row**.

I appreciate any assistance that you could provide. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you get rid of the `selection` in the code and reference the range through another mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip a row, you can break the `Cells` down into `Rows` and then use the condition to decide if the row should be run.  Really you break it into `Rows` first and the do the `Cells` of the each row.  This is most easily done if you know where `Missing Data` is going to show up.

**Code** includes your conditions and adds an outer loop to go through the `Selection` by `Rows`.

```
Sub SuppressN()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'go through by rows first
    Dim rng_row As Range
    For Each rng_row In rng_data.Rows
        If rng_row.Cells(1, 1) <> "Missing Data" Then
            'if good keep going on all the cells
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In rng_row.Cells
                If cell.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0" And cell.Value >= 1 And cell.Value <= 5 Then
                    cell.Value = "<6"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Picture shows before and after**

[image: before]
[image: after]

Note that I ran that code with the `NumberFormat` condition excluded since I did not want to emulate that.  I put it back in for the final code so that you don't have to change things.

This code requires that you have some reliable way of checking that somewhere in the row, `Missing Data` is present.  I just checked the first cell of the column (which sounds like what you have), but you can do this check a number of other ways (e.g. using `Find`, looping through and checking values, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly. All the best.